# Excel button to hide and reveal data in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

A quiz using Excel. Questions are randomised and displayed one at a time with the answer in the cell below, f9 changes the question/answer. I want to hide and reveal the answer by pressing a button. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? If you can post that it will enable others to give you the best advice.

Comment: I did something similar, where the correct answer is hidden if the student has not put anything in the answer box. Basic if() statement ie if blank, then blank etc if there is a result, compare to the correct answer and display either "Correct,Try again". Some say that "Wrong" is not "pc" any more... Avoids any issues with having macros and "enable macros" etc

Comment: This is minor, I would say... Can you show us the code triggered by Sheet `Calcualate` event? This code must clear the answer, not another button, I would suggest you. So, can you share the code showing randomized questions? And how your code make the evaluation between the correct answer and the one from the sheet cell? Basically, your code must contain a line: `Range("answer range").ClearContens`... Why to hide it? Will the next answer be placed in another cell?

Comment: Still alive? Do you really need help to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Create a button**

Click Insert -> shapes-> rectangle

Draw a rectangle and type show, draw another rectangle and type hide

Assume (row 6 contains answer)

---

**create two macro**

1. Click Developer tab-> Record Macro

give a Macro name "**hide**" click ok

Select row 6, Right-click and select Hide and click **stop recording** on the developer tab

Right-click hide (button)->assign a macro -> hide, click OK

2. Click Developer tab-> Record Macro

give a Macro name "**show**" click ok

Unhide Row 6 and click **stop recording**.

Right-click show(button)->assign a macro -> show, click OK

---

The Code will be

```
Sub show()
Rows("6:6").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Range("F5").Select
End Sub
```

```
Sub hide()
Rows("6:6").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Range("F5").Select
End Sub
```

Save the file with .xlsm as extension.

Click on show and hide alternatively will show and hide the row in excel

Comment: You could use something like `EntireRow.Hidden = Not(EntireRow.Hidden)` and use one button. `Hidden` equates to either TRUE or FALSE,so `Not(TRUE)` will be FALSE